# Deedle: how to load a bad formatted CSV file?

Tags: .net, csv, f#, deedle

I need to load many CSV files in Deedle. The problem is that they are bad formatted, since the first row has 8 columns, but the rest of data have 7 columns.
I tried to load them in Deedle, setting the "hasHeader" option to true, setting "inferTypes" to false and passing the schema, but I have always an error because of first row.

There is a way to say Deedle to skip one or more rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, and according to documentation, this should work (for csv file with three columns, no matter how many are provided in header):

```
let data = Frame.ReadCsv("sample.csv", hasHeaders=false, schema="R1,R2,R3")
```

But I believe there is a bug which ignores `schema` argument. Hence, the only solution I see is to use `Stream` and manually ignore first line of file:

```
using (File.OpenRead("sample.csv")) ( fun file ->
    while file.ReadByte() <> 10 do ()
    let data = Frame.ReadCsv(stream=file, schema = "R1,R2,R3", hasHeaders=true)
    // ...
)
```

which works for sample file:

```
Row1,Row2,Row3,Row4
1,2,3 
a,b,c
```

Comment: What is the `StreamReader` for?

Comment: @Daniel, good point, it was from previous tries. I've removed it.

Comment: @KonradKokosa, thank you for your answer. I tried to implement your snippet, but something is missing and I'm new to F# and .NET. Please, can you suggest me what is missing, or where to look for a solution? Thank you.

Comment: @FeliceBruno, what error do you have? Maybe you should use `open System.IO` to import namespace for `File`?

Comment: @KonradKokosa, I have the following error:

`Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.`

at the line where there is the code:
`let data = Frame.ReadCsv(stream=file, schema = "R1,R2,R3", hasHeaders=true)`.

and I'm already using `open System.IO`.

If I add a new line, like `stkData2.Rows`, then I have the following error:
`System.Exception: Schema was expected to have at most 5 items, but has 7`.

I have to say that the lines with different format are the first 2, the first has one column in excess, the second is empity. Can this be the problem?

Comment: @KonradKokosa, I found the problem. It was because the CSV file has the Italian numeric format instead of the English one, so the decimal separator is a comma, not a dot, and Deedle sees commas as default separators. I solved just setting parameters `separators="\t"` and `culture="it-IT"`. Thank you for your help.